# Is the final beta good enough for setting up a production server?

Tags: server, upgrade, 16.04

There is a new server, which would benefit from a lot of the newer packages coming with 16.04 as well as the newer kernel. As it will be taking over most tasks from the old one by the end of the month, a call needs to be made on the OS.

Running for a few days with 16.04 beta while all the stuff is being set up and configured on it, I gathered from various answers that it might still be buggy and will need many more upgrades while in beta, which is acceptable.

The only things I have not found an answer to is:

- **Will the additional package upgrades have any impact on performance down the line?** (I understand that the system should be in a more pristine state compared to post upgrade from 14.04, hence less dependency chaos and rubbish)
- **Could this lead to unforseeable security issues (kernel, etc)?**
- Would installing 14.04 and backporting the new packages be the better solution?

Comment: 16.04 release is literally a week away - are you not able to wait a week to put this server into production with an *actually released* version of Ubuntu?

Comment: If you're going to roll a Production server with Ubuntu, I would strongly suggest you use LTS releases.

Comment: @DopeGhoti 16.04 is LTS..?

Comment: The Beta isn't.

Comment: @ThomasW. The reason not to wait is that the final release is out, but all the setup is done while it is the final beta and more importantly it has the newer kernel and a lot of new packages from the get go.

Comment: @kcrk no it is not out.  16.04 releases on the 21st.  It is NOT the final release yet.

Comment: @ThomasW. Sorry I meant _FINAL BETA_ as described on the [release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule). So currently the latest release of xenial is RC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the final beta good enough for a production server?

No. A beta is -never- good enough for a live system.

> Will the additional package upgrades have any impact on performance down the line? (I understand that the system should be in a more pristine state compared to post upgrade from 14.04, hence less dependency chaos and rubbish)

The beta will have a daily download so if internet access is important that will have some impact. "impact on performance"... doubt we can answer that without knowing your hardware. If you run your server from a telephone 4G internet yes it will, if it is of a T1 ... not likely. But you also run the risk of introducing a bug during an update that kills your setup.

- Could this lead to unforseeable security issues (kernel, etc)?

No. You will run a risk during the beta period. But patches -improve- your system. Patches should not introduce other problems.

- Would installing 14.04 and backporting the new packages be the better solution?

Yes. But not the best option. I would set up the machine and take 2 weeks for testing. That way it is not a production server and it will be when 16.04 is released. We already have 16.04 set up in our google cloud. As soon as we see the updates fase out (probably 1 or 2 weeks after the 21st) those cloud instances become the live versions (we are setting our new systems up with http2 and mysql 5.7).

Comment: First of all thank you for the answers to my questions! How would you gage the updates phasing out? Either way around the middle of May it should be safe to put live?
On the performance question, I'm more interested in potential long term impact of all the additional updates that would never have been installed from a release cd especially with postgis, mariadb & mongo upgrading more frequently. The download won't make a dent in the 5Gbps link ... really not even a consideration. Are there any hiccups you have encountered so far?

Comment: @kcrk If you really want true stability (or as close as you can get), you should probably try something like RedHat, which is aimed at enterprises.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I was actually considering CoreOS. It looks very neat. Otherwise The crazy move would be Alpine Linux with docker or is that too crazy?

Comment: @kcrk not a single problem as of yet :D My -personal opinion-: Ubuntu server is rock solid. Every server release I have used since 6.06 was rock solid. Most we started using a month or so after release. 16.04 is the 1st we picked up before release to get a head start (due to us releasing new software next month we wanted also the benefits of MySQL 5.7). My -professional opinion: never go for a beta nor for a release that has not been tested thoroughly. Make sure you have a fallback. Either a 14.04 server or the knowledge on how to fix any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for a server you would be better to not only use an LTS version but for stability rather than cutting edge use an LTS version that has been tested *over some time*. Not the newest LTS (out for new release in a week) that has *not* been well and truly tested in the marketplace.

As an example look at Deamhost, which has hosted my website for many years:

```
        #                                    m                 
  mmm   #   m  m   m  mmmmm   mmm    mmm   mm#mm   mmm    m mm 
 #   "  # m"   "m m"  # # #  "   #  #   "    #    #"  #   #"  "
  """m  #"#     #m#   # # #  m"""#   """m    #    #""""   #    
 "mmm"  #  "m   "#    # # #  "mm"#  "mmm"    "mm  "#mm"   #    
                m"                                             
               ""                                              
Last login: Thu Apr 14 15:33:39 2016 from 124.149.186.113
xxxxxxxx@skymaster~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
xxxxxxxxxx@skymaster~$
```

And Precise Pangolin still has support until April 2017. Some thoughts on this Dreamhost blog about backporting, stability and other issues:

[Change Is In the Air’ – DreamHost Upgrades](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/2013/06/03/change-is-in-the-air-dreamhost-upgrades/)

I am not advocating that you should use an LTS that is this old, my recommendation is to use Trusty, which has support until April 2019.

Comment: Backporting can be tricky though. If OP needs newer packages, he's going to have a hard time.

Comment: @andrew.46 @Zacharee1 The package mess begins with having to add `nginx >1.7` and ends with a `docker-compose.yml` that's v2. The old server has been near enough unmanagable with 10+ additional repositories added. Upgrade one thing and spend days sorting out ependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off waiting until the 21st if you want 16.04. It is still in beta, and it could be hard to find support if something goes wrong.

However, if you really can't wait, 16.04 has reached its final freeze date, and the release candidate has been released today. I don't believe there are many changes (if any) in the week before the release.

It's ultimately up to you. You could risk somewhat unlikely (but very possible) issues if you install now, or you could wait a week for the stable release.

Also remember that the final 16.04 could be a little buggy still, but these issues will be fixed or lessened in future minor upgrades (16.04.1, 16.04.2, etc).